# How can I access the XAMPP 7.0.9 Security page?

Tags: php, apache, security, xampp

I have a hard time accessing the security page of xampp 7.0.9.

When I try to access http://localhost/security I get an object not found error.
If I try to access http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php I get an object not found error as well.

I tried to find an answer on the official webpage as well as the offical forums but didnt find anything that could be of help.

Answer (score 9):

Yes it seems like XAMPP has removed the security page. Their argument is that you'll not need the setting for a local environment.

The only problem for someone like me is that I have multiple test sites in my XAMPP server and in all of those test site I've set my mysql root a password. So, I need a mysql root password to be set (since I can't update all my test sites to no-password). I did it using the shell in XAMPP Control Panel

```
mysqladmin --user=root password "newpassword"
```

I encounter a new problem, PhpMyAdmin will not work anymore and the login page disappeared when you access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

For this I opened up **config.inc.php** file present inside **\xampp\phpMyAdmin\** and set the appropriate password there.

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue you are having. After doing lots of search in the internet, I just found this

> the "security" link FORTUNATELY hase gone, that link and actions were confusing and most Xampp users DESTROYED their installation after using it.

For details you may look here  [New Welcome XAMPP and docs](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=69810&start=15)

Comment: _Xampp is secure out of the box on local PCs, there is no more action required._ Thank you, best answer! There's very little on this but im used to the old insecure setup and now i can proceed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing the Access Denied page when you go to phpmyadmin after setting password for root then here is the solution. Go to config file (xampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php) and change **config** to **cookie** in the following line.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';

This will enable the login page and next time you go to phpmyadmin, you'll see a login page. Now login with your username and password. Hope this helps.