# PHP - XAMPP shows "Object not found" on http://localhost/security

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP & MySQL newly. According to the book, I downloaded XAMPP PHP 7.11 (32-bit) from the official website. I installed i and run as administrator. Then when I typed *http://localhost* it showed me a page like below:

[image: http://localhost]
But when I tried to look on the page *http://localhost/security* I am getting an Error page like below while the book & XAMPP FAQ page say it would should show something valid:

[image: http://localhost/security]

I really don't what's going on here, I'm feeling really stuck at this point because I need to add a password to MySQL database for my future project. I also looked up for several solution on the internet, but none of them helped. I also tried to uninstall this version and install XAMPP PHP 5.6.32 but all goes same !

Please help me. I'm sorry for my bad English and I'm a newbie in PHP learning.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I can't find any mention of the word security on https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html — which FAQ page are you talking about? What book are you talking about?

Comment: @Quentin I am referring to the FAQ "Is XAMPP Production ready?" where it says " If you want have your XAMPP accessible from the internet, you should go to the following URI which can fix some problems:

 http://localhost/security/"
and I reading the book "PHP & MySQL Novice to Ninja, 5th Edition" by Kevin Yank.

However, can you please tell me how to change passwords for MySQL instead of default "root" ?

Comment: There is a MySQL manual and a phpMyAdmin manual. You should start by reading those

Comment: @RiggsFolly , Thanks. Can you please tell me where i can find those? I barely knows about phpMyadmin and MySQL.

Comment: Google should become your best friend

Comment: Solución en este otro hilo:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590558/how-can-i-access-the-xampp-7-0-9-security-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590558/how-can-i-access-the-xampp-7-0-9-security-page)